# How to calculate a math type and give the result as you type in swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I am making a program that converts a number from decimal to binary for my college. 
I have written the script and functions in Swift with Xcode and it works very good. But now it works with a calculate button.
I want to remove the button code and return the result on the specific label while the users enters the number on the NSTextField.

How can this be done?
It is for an application for OSX environment.

I have below code on a view file with a convert button, which I want to remove.

```
import Cocoa

class DecimalView: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var decimalNumberText: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var toBinaryLabel: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func convertButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let binaryNumber = DecimalToBinary(Int(decimalNumberText.stringValue)!)
        toBinaryLabel.stringValue = binaryNumber

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()



        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

how it should be transformed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using NSTextField for input then set its delegate to self and use [NSTextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)NSTextFieldDelegate)'s **controlTextDidChange** delegate.

In this delegate you can call your conversion script and functions and display the result on your specific label.

```
import Cocoa

class DecimalView: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var decimalNumberText: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var toBinaryLabel: NSTextField!

func convertNumber() {
    let binaryNumber = DecimalToBinary(Int(decimalNumberText.stringValue)!)
    toBinaryLabel.stringValue = binaryNumber
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.

    decimalNumberText.delegate = self
}

override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification) {
    // Call your conversion functions here and display the result on label
    if obj.object as! NSTextField == decimalNumberText {
        self.convertNumber()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Interface Builder than hold Ctrl and drag a connection from textField to your ViewController and select delegate from the popup. If you are implementing it programmatically then write textField.delegate = self. In both cases you need to implement textDidChange: Delegate in your code.

Comment: I also added a Code Snippet in my answer for your help.

Comment: I have added the code that I have now on my question, how ti should be changed? Sorry, but I am quite new on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using an NSTextField. For this you have to use the  and its method `textDidChange:`. In this method just call your functions and set the value to label.

Reference from: [NSTextField value changed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textDidChange:)

Comment: yes, it is a NSTextField that gets the number that should be converted. So I should add the NSTextViewDelegate (should I declare this on the view?) ?

Comment: Yes, and set the text field's delegate in IB.

Comment: Can you give an example?